# Gradle build failed : cannot run a program

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I just installed android studio in Ubuntu again. I also installed all required sdk packages, but when I create any project it shows a message gradle build failed.

The error is about build tools, I have installed 2 build-tools **19.1.0** and **21.1.2** I also tried running project with build-tool 21.1.2 but it shows the same error.

The error is

```
Error:Error: Cannot run program "/opt/google/android/android-sdk/android-sdk-linux/build-
tools/19.1.0/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Error says **no such file or directory** but I checked in downloaded packages, there exists a file aapt even though it shows an error.

Please help me solving it.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. did u find a solution for this ?

Comment: @Droider yes, I solved it. It happens if you try to run 32 bit sdk on 64 bit os. [Here is my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148282/project-build-failed-in-android-studio-on-ubuntu/29149302#29149302), check it out

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions of this path for user you use to start Android Studio.

Comment: I don't know which path you are talking about. Could you please tell me explicitly?

Comment: @Apurva I mean "/opt/google/android/android-sdk/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/19.1.0/aapt". Try to execute `chmod -R 777 /opt/google/android/android-sdk`