# Gradle build failed in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, ubuntu, android-studio, gradle

I am using Android Studio on Ubuntu. I started Android Studio, created a "New Project" and started it with `Shift+F10`. It threw the following error:

```
/home/laptop/AndroidStudioProjects/TestIt420/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/drawable-mdpi-v4/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png
Error:Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/laptop/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Also it showed me a PNG file with a circle an a transparent background with file name: `abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_000.png`

After I just tried running the app again I now have 2 errors instead of one:

```
/home/laptop/AndroidStudioProjects/TestIt420/app/build/intermediates/explo     ded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/drawable-hdpi-     v4/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png
 Error:Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:      org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command      '/home/laptop/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero      exit value 127
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>     /home/laptop/AndroidStudioProjects/TestIt420/app/build/intermediates/explo    ded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.0.0/res/drawable-hdpi-    v4/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png: Error:     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command     '/home/laptop/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt'' finished with non-zero     exit value 127
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Can you maybe help me in resolving the issue?

Comment: Try running your app first and check for the errors in logcat

Comment: I can't run my app since this error is blocking me from starting it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android has not build SDK for ubuntu 64-bit yet, and from your error I can say you are using 32-bit SDK on 64-bit OS.

You need to **install 32-bit libraries** to run android SDK in ubuntu.

Start terminal and install following packages.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

and

Right click on the `.../AndroidSDK/sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt` file, open it's *Properties* and make sure you have **checked** *Allow executing file as a program* in the *Permissions* tab.

Comment: How do I go about making sure Allow executing file as a program is checked? Is there a way to edit the AAPT file? Is this done within the Studio GUI? Externally?

Comment: I'm getting this error as well. I am on Ubuntu 64-bit. Is this still applicable in August 2015?

Comment: @Donato I haven't tried this on Ubuntu 15.10 but up to 15.04 it works. Just write the commands and make aapt executable.

Comment: @Donato lib32z1 mentioned by Sudo should be installed as well

Answer (score 10):

You have to install These Packages to Solve this Error Because Android SDK Still not working on UBUNTU 64 Bit.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```