# aapt finished with non-zero exit value 127

Tags: android

For 2 days, I have been trying to get a blank android activity to compile on intellij idea ultimate on Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. This error has really stumped me:

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /home/guarddog/Documents/github/IcsTrac/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/22.2.1/res/drawable-ldrtl-hdpi/abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha.png: Error: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 127
```

Note I have Java 8, Gradle 2.5 and `/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools` all in my `$PATH`.

I tried the advice here: [Gradle build failed in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29148282/gradle-build-failed-in-android-studio). But the error still occurs. How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I meet the similar issue. I install lib32z1 and problem solved. Hope it could help.

Thanks @agustin.aliaga's answer in:

[finished with non zero exit value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value/30361914)

In my case, I had to install `libz.so.1` library to make it work, on Ubuntu 15.04 with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

Later, I make a deep survey and found to support 32bit Android platform in ubuntu 64 os, one should install the 32bit library.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6
```

Comment: This answer could be improved if you [edit] to explain how you discovered that you needed to install that

Answer (score 2):

I usually just do Build> Rebuild Project or Clean Project

if that doesn't work then I go File> Invalidate/Caches Restart and choose Invalidate and Restart

Answer (score 1):

Close Android Studio, delete `build` folders from your project location, than open AS and choose `rebuild` option.

Hope it help. Let me know if you still have that problem.

EDIT: Please, check also this issue:
[finished with non zero exit value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value/30361914)